# How does the following comparator even works while building up the min heap?

Tags: c++, heap

I know that if I build a heap using STL, it makes a max_heap. And if I want to make a min_heap, I will have to write my own custom comparator. Now, the following comparator,

```
struct greater1{
  bool operator()(const long& a,const long& b) const{
    return a>b;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<long> humble;
  humble.push_back(15);
  humble.push_back(15);
  humble.push_back(9);
  humble.push_back(25);

  std::make_heap(humble.begin(), humble.end(), greater1());
  while (humble.size()) {
    std::pop_heap(humble.begin(),humble.end(),greater1());
    long min = humble.back();
    humble.pop_back();  
    std::cout << min << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The above code I got from off of the internet. I just have one doubt. How is the comparator actually working. And as far as I understand, shouldn't it be something like, `return a < b` because we want the minimum element to be in the front and then the bigger element in the heap. Why is it `return a > b`. Doesn't it mean that, `if (a>b)`, then this will return true and `a` will be put in the heap before `b` and therefore a bigger element is put in front of a smaller element?

Comment: the default comparator is "less-than". if with that comparator, the algorithm builds a max-heap, then with the reversed comparator, it will build a min-heap. BTW, you don't need to write the custom comparator, just use `std::greater`. You don't need to take the `long`s by reference either.

Comment: Yay, answers in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're reading too much into a connection between the comparator semantics and the heap semantics. Remember, the internal details and structure of containers are deliberately abstracted away from you so, the moment you started trying to rationalise about this in terms of how you think the internal structure of a `max_heap` should look, you got carried away.

In the standard library, default comparators are *always* `less-than`. If the relationship between elements for sorting within the particular container/algorithm is not `less-than`, the container/algorithm will be clever enough to make that transformation (in this case, on usual implementations, by simply passing the operands in the reverse order, like `cmp(b,a)`!). But, fundamentally, it will always start with a `less-than` ordering because that is the consistent convention adopted.

So, to invert the ordering of your container, you would take a `less-than` comparator and turn it into a `greater-than` comparator, no matter what the physical layout of the container's implementation may (in your opinion) turn out to be.

Furthermore, as an aside, and to echo the Croissant's comments, I would take `long`s by value … and, in fact, just use `std::greater` rather than recreating it.

Comment: Great answer. Understood it. But there are some places where I have to write my own custom comparator and it's not related to STL at all. For example, I was solving a question on printing all anagrams together, and in that case, the comparator had, `return a < b` where `a` and `b` are strings. What does that mean then?

Comment: @JohnLui: What do you mean "what does that mean"?

Comment: I mean what is the logic behind writing, `return a < b` here? Shouldn't it be something like, `return a > b`?

Comment: @JohnLui: Why?​ Perhaps you missed the part of my answer where I explain that `less-than` is the conventional default comparator. You can pick `greater-than` if you like but prepare for everything to come out backwards. Asking "why" is vacuous in this context.

Comment: But, if I have a list of strings like `abc def bca fed`, if I use the above comparator, how is it grouping all the anagrams and returning `abc bca def fed`. What is the logic behind using `return a<b` for these set of strings? This is my only doubt. Also, by convention, you said it's less than, therefore, what is the rationale behind using less than here?

Comment: @JohnLui: I still don't understand your question. It's a little like asking "why does the colour blue look blue?". It just does. You'll have to refine it.

Answer (score 0):

Standard heap builds in such a way that for every element `a` and its child `b`, the comparison `cmp(b,a)` holds, where `cmp` is the comparator supplied. Note that the first argument to `cmp` is the *child*. (Or, abstracting from the internal representation, the standard way is so that `cmp(top, other)` is true for the first element `top` and any other `other`.)

This is obviously done to make the default comparator ("less") build max-heap.

So you need to provide a comparator which you want to return true when a *child* is supplied as a first argument. For the min-heap, this will be 'greater'.